# Criar uma tabela com datas

Tags: c#, data, datatable

Estou criando uma tabela e preciso que as colunas sejam criadas da seguinte maneira: 
Seg, 23 Nov | Ter,24 Nov | Qua,25 Nov | Qui,26 Nov | Sex,27 Nov | Sab,28 Nov | Dom, 29 Nov

Para criar a Tabela eu passo por parâmetro uma data(que é selecionada através de um calendário)

Estou fazendo assim para criar a Tabela:

```
    DateTime diaAgenda = 'Data que foi selecionada no calendario';

    public DataTable gerarAgenda(DateTime dia)
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

        string diahoje = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dia);

        tabela.Columns.Add("" + diahoje);

        for (int data = 1; data < 7; data++)
        {
            dia = dia.AddDays(1);
            diahoje = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dia);
            tabela.Columns.Add("" + diahoje);
        }
        return tabela;            
    }
```

Fazendo dessa forma a tabela que eu gero fica com as seguintes colunas:

Qui,26 Nov | Sex,27 Nov | Sab,28 Nov | Dom, 29 Nov | Seg, 30 Nov | Ter,01 Dez | Qua,02 Dez |

Como eu poderia fazer para criar as colunas assim:

Seg, 23 Nov | Ter,24 Nov | Qua,25 Nov | Qui,26 Nov | Sex,27 Nov | Sab,28 Nov | Dom, 29 Nov

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem confusa. Por que não consegues fazer que a primeira coluna seja segunda?

Comment: porque eu não sei como definir que a semana sempre inicie na segunda..

Comment: Pra que serve o parâmetro `dia`? Você está gerando uma tabela com base nele?

Comment: Pergunta ruim gera respostas ruins :)

Comment: Realmente @bigown. Você viu aquele `switch-case` na segunda resposta? Será que é o caso de votar para fechar como **não está clara o suficiente**?

Comment: @jbueno o parâmetro eu passo o dia..

Comment: Isso eu percebi pelo nome do mesmo. A questão é: pra que serve o parâmetro?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu entendi o seu problema então diria que é simplesmente o parâmetro `dia` que você esta passando. Você não esta passando ele marcando uma Segunda-feira, por isso ocorre o "erro" de não começar na segunda como você deseja.

```
public DataTable gerarAgenda(DateTime dia)
{
    switch(dia.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: dia.AddDays(-1); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: dia.AddDays(-2); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday: dia.AddDays(-3); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday: dia.AddDays(-4); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday: dia.AddDays(-5); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday: dia.AddDays(-6); break;
    }

    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

    string diahoje = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dia);

    tabela.Columns.Add("" + diahoje);

    for (int data = 1; data < 7; data++)
    {
        dia = dia.AddDays(1);
        diahoje = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dia);
        tabela.Columns.Add("" + diahoje);
    }
    return tabela;            
}
```

Comment: Como eu marco para o dia = Segunda feira?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar se é segunda feira dessa forma..

```
if(dia == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
```

Comment: `Saturday`? '-'

Comment: @jbueno ...maldito... Nem vou editar ficar com seus dois pontos uteis shuahs ....Monday .... `if(dia == DayOfWeek.Monday )`

Comment: Mas em fim, fui o primeiro a dar a dica o resto foi copia

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Vc quer que a primeira coluna seja a SEGUNDA FEIRA, é isso?
Testa aí:

```
var diaDaSemana = (int) dia.DayOfWeek;
var inicioDaSemana = dia.AddDays(diaDaSemana-1);
for (int dias = 1; dias < 7; dias++)
{
    data = inicioDaSemana.AddDays(dias);
    dataFormatada = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", data);
    tabela.Columns.Add("" + dataFormatada);
}
```

Mas aproveitando a deixa, parece muito anti produtivo - ou até mesmo inadequado - o que vc está tentando fazer.

Recomendo dar uma refatorada nesse código. Está muito estranho o resultado final dele.